# pytest assert message customization with variable introspection

Tags: python, rest, testing, pytest, pytest-django

In the [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#defining-your-own-assertion-comparison) it says that you can customize the output message when an `assert` fails. I want to customize the `assert` message when testing a REST API method it returns an invalid status code:

```
def test_api_call(self, client):
    response = client.get(reverse('api:my_api_call'))
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

So I tried to put a piece of code like this in `conftest.py`

```
def pytest_assertrepr_compare(op, left, right):
    if isinstance(left, rest_framework.response.Response):
        return left.json()
```

But the problem is `left` is the actual value of `response.status_code` so it's an `int` instead of a `Response`. However the default output messages throws something like:

> E       assert 400 == 201 E        +  where 400 = .status_code

Saying that the error 400 comes from an attribute `status_code` of a object `Response`.

My point is that there is a kind of introspection of the variable being evaluated. So, how can I customize the assert error message in a comfortable way to get a similar output to example posted above?

Answer (score 48):

you could use Python built-in capability to show custom exception message:

```
assert response.status_code == 200, f"My custom msg: actual status code {response.status_code}"
```

Or you can built a helper assert functions:

```
def assert_status(response, status=200):  # you can assert other status codes too
    assert response.status_code == status, \
        f"Expected {status}. Actual status {response.status_code}. Response text {response.text}"

# here is how you'd use it
def test_api_call(self, client):
    response = client.get(reverse('api:my_api_call'))
    assert_status(response)
```

also checkout: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I know the both solutions that you propose and sure that both will work. However I was looking for a fancy solution where you can still use `assert` and you won't need  to write more code.

Comment: ahh, sorry, didn't get your question intent

Comment: The first example in the above response is exactly what I was looking for!